# Excel - Error handling - changing text of one cell based on another cell

Tags: excel

Trying to finish up all my error handling formulas. I have one left that is giving me some trouble.

If **Cell B7** is any text I want **Cell A8** to say `check Lw_Lw value to make sure it is a number`

[image: Snip of Excel table]

Comment: Did you tried `=ISNUMBER(B7)`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried several variations of IF(ISNUMBER(B7),"check Lw_Lw value to make sure it is a number") AND IF(ISTEXT(B7),"check Lw_Lw value to make sure it is a number"), but both of these come back with A8 displaying error #VALUE!

Comment: I have tried `=IF(ISNUMBER(B7),"check Lw_Lw value to make sure it is a number")` and it does ***not*** give an error. In order for this function to return an error B7 must contain an error, perhaps caused by a formula residing there. That would change the task and leave the invitation to "enter" a value there void.

Answer (score 0):

You may like to try this formula in A8.

```
=IFERROR("Value for "&INDEX($B3:$E3,1,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER($B7:$E7)=FALSE,0))&" must be numeric","")
```

Note that it's an array formula. If you have a version of Excel earlier than 365 it must be entered using Ctl+Shift+Enter.

The formula will examine B7:E7 for non-numeric values. If one is found it will issue a text like "Value for Lw_Lw must be numeric", where "Lw_Lw" is taken from B3:E3, matching the first column where a non-numeric entry was found.

The formula will deem blank cells to be non-numeric. Therefore the user will be prompted to enter a numeric value for each of the 4 cells and the notice in A8 will change as he continues to comply. If you prefer to show no message until all 4 cells have been filled, embed the formula in a COUNTA() function as shown below, where the above function takes the place of the `True` result.

```
=If(CountA($B7:$E7)=4, True, "")
```

Comment: I just got the formula to work. I had a conditional formula that was interfering with it working correctly. Once I deleted the conditional formula, I used =IF(ISTEXT(B7),"check Lw_Lw value to make sure it is a number", in A8 cell and it worked. Thank you guys for your help!

Comment: Your comment doesn't relate to this answer. You may still wish to look at it because it goes further than your original question. Also note that forum etiquette requires you to mark an answer you used as `Selected`. Answers without such mark are automatically deemed of lesser value or, if they are the only ones, irrelevant.